# What does the text "Red if ailing" mean on page 2 (Elemental/Ailment Resistance) of character status?

Tags: disgaea

On page 2 of the character status menu, the text "Elemental/Ailment Resistance" is followed by the text "Red if ailing" in parentheses. What does this mean? The words suggest that it means that the resistance for a particular status ailment will be displayed in red if the character is presently suffering from that status ailment; but that doesn't happen. The only text colour change triggered by a status ailment that I've seen is the character name, hit points and spell points being displayed in green in the hospital menu. Does "Red if ailing" refer to something completely different?